# Android - Center TextView Horizontally in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, layout-gravity

I have the following basic layout

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/title_bar_background">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="HELLO WORLD" />

    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout>
```

It seems like the xml is correct but the text is aligned to the left. The textview takes up the entire width of the parent and the textview is set to be centered. Not sure what the problem is...

Comment: try android:gravity="center" for your textview

Answer (score 239, accepted):

What's happening is that since the the TextView is filling the *whole* width of the inner LinearLayout it is already in the horizontal center of the *layout*. When you use `android:layout_gravity` it places the widget, as a whole, in the gravity specified. Instead of placing the whole widget center what you're really trying to do is place the *content* in the center which can be accomplished with `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` and the `android:layout_gravity` attribute can be removed.

Comment: If I understand correctly he could change "android:layout_width="fill_parent"  to "wrap_content" and then use android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal".  Am I right ?

Comment: @bluesm No, the inner LinearLayout doesn't allow itself to have space that is not filled with a View (not considering the case of an empty LinearLayout). Thus the the `android:layout_width` will have the same value (after layout). Since the width of the TextView is equal to the with of the inner LinearLayout the TextView effectively has the `android:layout_gravity` values of `left`, `right`, and `center` at the same time.

Comment: For `ImageView` its `layout_gravity`and for `TextView` its `gravity` is what **only** works. Android is great ! Thanks to all beautiful SO posts without which development was just impossible.

Comment: don't forget about           `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Answer (score 26):

If you set `<TextView>` in center in `<Linearlayout>` then first put `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` compulsory
No need of using any other gravity

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linear_profile" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">
            <TextView 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="It's.hhhhhhhh...."
                android:textColor="@color/Black"

                />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 24):

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/title_bar_background">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="HELLO WORLD" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 18):

Use `android:gravity="center"` in `TextView` instead of `layout_gravity`.

Comment: Short and precise answer. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Just use: **android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"**

It will put the whole textview in the center